# Using vector in c++ and debugging it lead to Exception

Tags: c++

[image]

As mentioned in the title, on debugging C++ code an Exception occurred(as seen in the picture). How can I overcome it?

It's my code that induces Exception.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;
    std::vector<int> v(t);

    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> v[i];
    }
    
    for(const auto& e : v)
    {
        std::cout << e << '\n';
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Usually, that exception happens when you access indices that don't exist in the vector - but you don't appear to be doing that.

Comment: It would be helpful to know where in your code the error appears. Are you giving it a very large number for size?

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact code that raises the exception? The code works without any problem for me. Which numbers did you add when the exception was raised? What line raises the exception?

Comment: Are you sure that `t` is positive?

Comment: Could you share the value of `t` when you encounter the crash?

Comment: Why are you using an rvalue there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all guys.
I finally solve this problem. It occurred when debug mode has been changed x86 to x64 in VS.
but I still dont know why these exceptions occurred when debug mode is x64, I just guess that's maybe occurred when last debugging is proceeded on x86 mode at the same project.